# C derenferencing pointer to character array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to grasp C pointers with this small example I found in a tutorial:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char vowels[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    char *pvowels = &vowels;

    printf(pvowels);
//  printf(*pvowels);
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this I get a warning "Initialization from incompatable pointer type" but it will still compile/run, printing AEIOU plus some random junk characters. I was also under the assumption that *pvowels would be the character at the first memory location of the vowels array and hence print an 'A' but it just segfaults instead.

My two questions are:

Why does the 1st printf print out the vowels + junk?

Why does the 2nd print not print out just an A?

Comment: ... and you're entirely unconcerned about the type error in line 5?

Comment: No, but it was a warning not an error. So I guess it is coercing something poorly?

Comment: `*pvowels` is the first character, but `printf` takes a string, not a character. That's also a type error.

Comment: Why not treat warnings as errors?

Comment: Good point, I guess I just trusted that the tutorial had a reason for doing this and I didn't question it. The first 5 lines were directly from it. The printf's were mine trying to understand what line 5 was doing.

Comment: A warning is an error you *might* be able to get away with. Don't *ever* count on it. Set up your compiler/IDE to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: "The first 5 lines were directly from it." You probably should ditch that tutorial and find a betrer one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `&vowels` you get a pointer to the *array* not the first element in the array. The type of `&vowels` is `char(*)[5]`.

To fix this problem you should either use `&vowels[0]` to get a pointer to the first element, or rely on that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element:

```
char *pvowels = vowels;
```

The second problem is that you treat `pvowels` like a *string*, but a string is a sequence of characters *with a terminator*. Since the array `vowels` doesn't have this terminator the `printf` call will go out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*.

As for the last problem, when you dereference a pointer you get the value of the location where it points. Because the location of the array starts with the first element of the array both `&vowels[0]` and `&vowels` points to the same location, so when you dereference `pvowels` you get the first element of the array which is the character `'A'`. ***However*** you can't use it as the first argument for `printf` because the `printf` function expects it to be a *string* (a pointer to a zero-terminated array of characters), not a single character.

Comment: It should be noted that the use of `printf(pvowels);` is not good and can cause problem if a string contains `%s` in it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I totally forgot about character array termination. I also didn't realize a pointer to an array was different from a pointer to the first element of the array.